# Validation on selection of past time for Today

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, timepicker

I am trying to provide the time selection facility to end user. with a restriction that if user selects today's date and trying to select time . the end user should not allowed to select the time for today which is already passed.

the challenge which I facing here is the bootstrap date picker works with a format. comparison need on different system formats.

How can I compare to date, make them in one format so I can do comparison and then check for time validation.

I am using `bootstrap time picker and date picker`.

I have tried but got stuck on different formats and time comparison.

```
var tDate = $('#RequestToDate').val();
var now = new Date();
var twoDigitMonth = ((now.getMonth().length + 1) == 1) ? (now.getMonth() + 1) : (now.getMonth() + 1);
var currentDate = twoDigitMonth + "/" + now.getDate() + "/" + now.getFullYear();
now = now.getHours() + ':' + now.getMinutes();
if (tDate.toString() == currentDate) {
    if (ftime <= now || totime <= ftime) {
        //Show A Error message
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/), it has very nice functions for converting dates to and from different formats.

This section of the documentation is pertinent to your question: http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-format/

You can create a 'moment' from a string like this:

```
moment("12-25-1995", "MM-DD-YYYY");
```

The first argument is the string input, the second argument is a format you define so moment.js knows which part of the string equals day, month, year, etc.

Once you have all your times as 'moments' you can easily compare them, change them and output them in different formats.

Moment.js also has functions for comparing: http://momentjs.com/docs/#/query/is-before/